# How would this trade be taxed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, trading, lending

I am wondering about the tax implications for the following scenario:

Say I am domiciled in the USA and have some stocks, which I think will go down vs USD. Rather than sell them and buy back later (which would incur capital gains by assumption), I lend the stocks to some entity, and borrow some other asset (other stocks, say) which are correlated with my original stocks.

I then sell the asset I borrowed for USD. In the event that my bet is correct, I can buy the asset back lower, return the asset to pay off my loan, and get my stocks back. I will have some extra USD left over (the profit).

Is this profit considered income? Are there any other taxes relevant to this scenario?

Comment: What country are you in? Tax questions need a country tag.

Comment: I'm a bit lost by the process, however most (if not all) platforms that loan you money for stocks will only offer you a % of its value, for example 70%. If the value of the stock you gave as collateral goes below what they gave you, they liquidate the stock to recoup the money. If you use the loaned money to buy other stocks which you resell for profit, you'll have to pay tax on that profit. Then you'll repay your loan and get your stocks back which are now worth less so you suffer a loss on that if you decide to then sell it.  Not sure if I got it correctly though

Comment: A direct short-against-the-box is only an intermediate "constructive sale" and not an ultimate constructive sale if not carried across the year-end. The intermediate constructive sale does require a payment of estimated quarterly taxes but those payments can be refunded. I suppose that short-against-the-box requires two accounts or requires a sub-account. Otherwise and furthermore, hedging with options is not a constructive sale. So make a collar, write an out-of-the-money call-option and use the funds to buy an out-of-the-money put option

Comment: A pretty safe assumption is that anything you would call profit, your tax authority would call income.

Comment: @SSpring if at any stage either the put or call for the collar get exercised, then I need to either sell the stocks to honor the call I wrote, or I have the right to sell them at a favorable price if I exercise the put. Either way I am selling the stocks, and paying capital gains (if any), right?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Sorry, I thought the reference to USD made it clear. I'll edit the question .

Comment: An in-the-money call-write can often be closed-out for a loss but taxes on years-and-years of unrealized capital gains are avoided. An in-the-money long-put can often be closed-out for a gain and again taxes on years-and-years of capital-gains would be avoided. Hopefully, the bid-ask spread of the options is small on the last day.

Comment: Fascinating! Thank you. If you want to copy your comment as an answer I will accept because it is very much in the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a related method:

A direct short-against-the-box is only an intermediate "constructive sale" and not an ultimate constructive sale if it is not carried across the year-end as within a time period. The intermediate constructive sale does require a payment of estimated quarterly taxes but those payments can be refunded. I suppose that the short-against-the-box requires two accounts or requires a sub-account.

Otherwise and furthermore:

Hedging with options is not a constructive sale. So to make a collar, write an out-of-the-money call option and use the funds to buy an out-of-the-money put option.